# Conversion of V2 Ninject Binding to V3

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

I've been banging my head at this for about 8 hours now, and I just can't seem to find a simple explanation on how to change my custom bootstrapper for ninject (Last worked on the code back in v2.x.x.x) to the new v3.0.0.0 syntax.

I currently have the following:

```cs
public class NinjectCustomBootStrapper : NinjectNancyBootstrapper
{
  protected override Ninject.IKernel GetApplicationContainer()
  {
    return Program.MyContainer;
  }

}
```

in a septate class, and :

```cs
public static IKernel MyContainer
{
  get { return _myContainer ?? (_myContainer = CreateKernel()); }
  set { _myContainer = value; }
}

private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
  var kernel = new StandardKernel();
  kernel.Bind<CardMonitorService>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
  return kernel;
}
```

in my main program 'Program.c' in a command line app.

Iv'e since updated ninject to V3.0.0.0 only to find that there's been some breaking changes.  I'll admit I don't use ninject very often (I usually use structuremap), and the only reason this project does is I didn't write it originally.

Since I've upgraded Ninject, now when the app is started up I get the following exception:

```cs
Method not found: 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax`1<!0>
Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax`1.ToConstant(!0)'.
```

After a ton of searching and researching, the closest I've been able to find is this:

http://sharpfellows.com/post/Ninject-Auto-registration-is-changing-in-version-3.aspx

Which while it points me in the right direction, still isn't quite a solution as I'm not using a custom binding generator.

So my question is this.

How do I rewrite the above so that my project once again works and the WCF service when called gets the correct singleton binding handed to it when a request comes in.  Going back to ninject 2 is not an option, as other dependencies in the project that have been added have forced the v3 upgrade and these add new functionality that's been requested hence why I'm working on it.

For reference this is a .NET4 build, running on NancyFX with a self hosting WCF setup as a windows service using Topshelf to provide the SCM interface.

Cheers

Shawty

**Addendum to clear things up a little**

This is an existing project that was originally written sometime back, I've been asked to add some new features to the project.

As part of adding these new features I have been required to upgrade the version of Ninject being used from an earlier version to V3.0.0.0 as newer dependencies added to the project require the newer version of Ninject.

Under the previous V2 of Ninject the code I have given above worked fine, with no issues, since the project has had Ninject V3 added I now get the exception as described above.

I cannot go back to the earlier version of Ninject as that will mean not being able to add the new functionality that I'm adding.

From the research I've done so far the sharpfellows link above is the closest explanation of my issue that I've managed to find so far on the internet.

I don't use Ninject very often, so I've not got the background to know what's changed between V2 & V3 that (based on my research) is the cause of my issue.

I need to know how to change my code written under V2 (and shown above) so that it works under V3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a week or so it turns out that the problem was that the Nancy dev team broke binary comparability with the latest version of ninject (or vice versa) :-)

There is a GitHub pull request to fix this available at :

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject/pull/6

However the next version 'Nancy.Bootstrapper.Ninject' 0.12 will be out on NuGet soon which will have the fix implemented.

Answer (score 2):

`MissingMethodException` is usually a deployment problem. You compile against a different assembly than you deploy. Check that you deployed the same version and same build.

Comment: Not sure I follow you Remo.  I'm getting this exception at build time.  That is, in my project, I compile, Build then run and the app immediately aborts with the exception given.  Just to clarify there is no deploy here, all this is occurring before any deployment takes place.

Comment: Then I missunderstood your question. I understood from "when the app is started up I get the following exception" that it is a runtime exception.

Comment: Ah sorry, I can see where you got that from.  Let me add a bit to the above and clear it up a little.

Comment: Then you have to add the line that gives you the compilation error. I don't see any line with ToConstructor() in your question.

Comment: It don't get a line reported Remo, the only error I get is what's posted above, from what I've worked out it seems to be missing from my custom bootstrapper (the first bit of code I added) however I don't know the signature I need or the function layout to be added.

Comment: Reading you first comment again this is a runtime exception! And you most likely have a deployment issue. E.g. your NinjectNancyBootstrapper is built against Ninject 2.2 and your application uses 3.0 which won't work.

Comment: That's what I think too Remo, how do I need to code it so that it works with V3?

Comment: Update Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject to a version built against Ninject 3.0

Comment: That's exactly my problem Remo, I have.  I'm building against V3 the code I have doesn't work with V3 only with V2, I need to know how to re-write it to be compatible with V3.

Comment: Again you don't need to change your code but your deployment! All the libraries (including Nancy.Bootstrappers.Ninject!) you are using need to be compiled against Ninject 3.0!

Comment: Nope I need to re-write the code to work the way it should with V3, If I build & deploy with V2 everything works fine, but I cannot deploy with V2 anymore only with V3, nancy is built against V3, nancy-ninject is V3, ninject itself is V3, everything is V3 except for my code given above, unless of course your telling me the code I'm using (as shown above) should be compatible with V3 in which case I need to figure out why all compatible assemblies are not compatible. The actual exception I get is raised in MY code too not nancy or anywhere else.

Comment: Ok, so if that's the case and my code should work under V3 that's great, I'm happy with that.  If it is a deployment issue, then surely I'm not the only one having problems, I did an update off NuGet so ALL the packages I'm using are the latest versions, have there been any other complaints that you know of?  Can you confirm if the latest Ninject packages on you tube are the most up-to date and are compatible?

Comment: The issue is that one of the Nuget packages (Prism.NinjectExtension) hasn't been updated to use Ninject v3.